# Getting "apt-get update does not have a Release file" and "Failed to fetch <IP_address_of_the_local_repository>"during `apt-get update`

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates, proxy

I have a local Ubuntu repository:

[image]

It clearly shows the release file. So, when I do `apt-get update` from another computer configured to get its updates from the local repo, why does it say, "apt-get update does not have a Release file"?

Below is a screenshot of the errors and warnings I get. I do notice that "apt-get update does not have a Release file" shows up as a warning in the output, but I thought maybe it has something to do with the error which is "Failed to fetch ".

[image]

I must inform that the machine where I want to do the `apt-get update` is behind a proxy. (The other machine is also behind the same proxy.) So, I tried the following:

1. sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy

`Acquire::http::Proxy “http://username:password@proxy_ip:port“;`

2.

```
sudo apt-get clean 
cd /var/lib/apt 
sudo mv lists lists.old 
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
```

3.
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf

`Acquire::http::Timeout "1";`

(I did this only because it was taking a long time to display the errors)

4.
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/piplining-off.conf

`Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth "0";`

None of these are helping. What I do notice is that when I switch off the proxy, I can `wget` the files from the local repository.

```
wget http://160.88.114.18/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
--2017-12-22 15:19:19--  http://160.88.114.18/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
Connecting to 160.88.114.18:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7228243 (6.9M)
Saving to: ‘Packages’

Packages                                                   100%[========================================================================================================================================>]   6.89M  --.-KB/s    in 0.06s
```

Also, I should mention that the local mirror has only stuff downloaded from www.archive.ubuntu.com, and no other PPAs have been added to the `sources.list` of the target machine. So, it couldn't be a case of extinct PPAs. Any help is appreciated.